# Windows 10 won't update until Samsung Easy Settings is uninstalled manually

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update, windows-10-v1703

When I try to run the [Samsung] **Easy Settings** uninstall so that I can update Windows 10 to v1703 (Creators Update), Windows 10 blocks the uninstaller from running the Easy Settings uninstall saying that it is for a different version of Windows and might be unsafe.

I can't seem to find any valid or manual solutions on Samsung or Microsoft sites so I am posting my manual "uninstall" solution here for everyone else.

Answer (score 0):

**Uninstall Samsung Easy Settings manually and with little effort.** (even for a novice)

*Firstly I want to emphasize that you should attempt to uninstall Samsung Easy Settings and any other programs the Windows 10 update is telling you to uninstall the proper way by opening windows settings "Add or Remove Programs" (or Apps & Features) section and then uninstalling it. If you are not able to uninstall it the normal way - then follow my instructions.*

1. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> (all three at once) to open your task manager (or open it the way you're most comfortable).
2. In the Task Manager Processes tab you'll want to locate every process that says either "Easy Settings", or "Samsung Easy", or possibly some other variations. Also you'll want to do this for each of the following "S Agent", "Samsung Agent", "Samsung Update", or similarly named samsung processes. You'll use each one of these in the next steps...
3. Right click each one of these 1 at a time and select "Open File Location" from the menu that appears. A folder will soon open with the executable file for this process highlighted somehow. Follow step 4 for this file and each additional one if any you find through the Task Manager.
4. If the file in fact lies somewhere within a "Samsung" related folder*** and seems to be related to Easy Settings** Samsung Update**, or Samsung Agent**,  you will then rename the file by simply placing an X in front of the name (filename.exe to Xfilename.exe). You will probably have to provide administrator credentials to do this and at the same time take note of the file location in the case that you want to reverse anything in the future by simply removing the X from the file name. *

   *** Make sure each executable is within a Samsung related folder and that it seems to be directly related to Easy Settings, Samsung Update, or Agent.

   ** Don't just go renaming every process/file that relates to Samsung - as long as it is related to samsung and has "easy" or "agent" in its name somewhere you should be good to go - but still use a little judgement - I can't possibly know everything.

   * Don't overdo it, just rename the 1 file that goes with the process you're working on and pay no attention to the rest of the files in that folder for now/ever.
5. After doing this for every process related to Samsung Easy Settings, you will have one last task and that is the "dreaded" registry edit (I'll make it fun and easy in step 6+)
6. On your Windows 10 bar click the Circle\Cortiana thing (next to or near the Window icon) and type REGEDIT in the search box - then open regedit and then you'll have to grant administrator privileges to do so completely.
7. In the Registry Editor select Edit->Find from the menu and type in "Easy Settings" (without quotes), and make sure the Values and Data checkboxes are selected (Select Keys too - why not) - and click the Find button. Likely it will find the entry in a folder with a mostly unreadable name (a bunch of letters and numbers). You'll go through the registry finding each entry with Easy Settings that meets step 8's requirements. (It will likely only be one entry, but maybe 2)
8. Very important... If you find a registry entry for Easy Settings that lies within one of the following 2 paths only (ignoring all others unless you know better) you will first Click (to make sure it is the right folder) and then if the data still has easy settings in it - right click the same highlighted (or encircled/squared) folder and select delete. Below are the only (as far as I know) following paths where it is safe to delete Easy Settings registry entries from so if you're in this path you should be 99.99% good to go (you can always back up your registry first, which is a good practice I will not teach here - do a search for it).

   ```
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall         
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
   ```
9. Now go check/refresh your Windows Settings "Apps & Features" to see if Easy Settings has been removed from the list. If it has, you've done good! Now try restarting your Windows Update to see if we did real good (you might have to restart your computer first) - you also might still get an error, in that case reload and retry to perform the update (could take a few tries - and you might have to restart your computer each time). But it will eventually work (especially if you don't get the annoying "Easy Settings" must be uninstalled first message again - and if you do - try steps 1 through 10 again following them more closely this time)

   Now you might lose some of the "Easy" button functionality on your Samsung device in doing this, but It had to be done to update Windows so this is expected. Check Samsung for any updates for their Easy Settings (I think they just call it Samsung Settings or something now), and any other relevant official Samsung updates/software for your device.

Comment: You should condense your answer down by removing the commentary.  Just stick to what you did to solve your problem.  This also seems to have been copied for some place, since you mention skipping step 9, please quote and cite your source

Comment: Yeah, I copied it from the place I wrote the original as I was figuring it out on my computer... And from Stackoverflow because it was a bit off topic for coding (will delete that one later). Skipping step 9 was a Windows joke... The commentary is there for novice users, as I expect a lot of inexperienced people will have my issue, find this post, and need a bit of extra support to keep them from pulling their hair out.

Comment: We really don't need the commentary though.  There is a difference if you want to emphasize something specific, but "After not finding anything useful to uninstall Samsung Easy Settings on my Windows 10 computer I had to figure this out on my own (trust me - I'm a coder ;-)" is commentary that doesn't serve a purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend - to any still facing this problem - to backup the Easy Settings version and find the proper installer before.

In my experience,
it works adapting it to W7 compatibility once reinstalled after the needed OS upgrades.

The new Samsung Settings do not work properly for every **Fn key**.

Answer (score 0):

If one of you is still fighting to get Easy Settings to work on Windows 10, here is what I did to finally get backlit keyboard back on a Samsung Series 9 NP900X3C-A03FR after installing Windows 10 version 1709 (Fall Creator Update) :
- You will want to get version 2.1 of Samsung Settings (new name of this utility).
- First install the latest version of Samsung Software Update :
http://downloadcenter.samsung.com/content/SW/201305/20130521090434453/SWUpdate_2.1.15.1.ZIP
- Use Compatibility Mode to install this.
- Launch Software Update and type in your Samsung model number in the upper right corner.
- Select Windows 10: you will get a list of software and utilities to download.
- You will need Samsung Settings for the Fn keys for backlit keyboard and Display Manager for the screen backlight control.
- Select these items and click Export.
- The downloaded software goes into a folder named SystemSoftware.
- Install the software in Compatibility Mode and restart computer. Works!